# What is the difference between Microdata or Schema.org (or can I use both)?

Tags: 7

I am building a community site in Drupal 7.

I am using the SEO checklist, which suggest to use the [microdata](https://drupal.org/project/microdata) module.

Other places I read are suggesting to use [Schema.org](https://drupal.org/project/schemaorg) module.

what is difference between them? Can I use both modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are [different things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17589792/1591669):

- [Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#microdata) is a **syntax**.
- [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) is a **vocabulary**.

If you want to use the Schema.org vocabulary, you can use the syntax Microdata, or [RDFa](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/) ([Lite](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-rdfa-lite-20150317/)), or [JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/) (or any other RDF serialization, but the three mentioned syntaxes are supported by the big search engines that sponsor Schema.org).

---

The [schemaorg](https://drupal.org/project/schemaorg) module integrates the Schema.org vocabulary into Drupal 7 by using RDFa 1.0, which is the syntax used by Drupal 7 for other vocabularies, too.

The [microdata](https://www.drupal.org/project/microdata) integrates the Schema.org vocabulary by using Microdata (without this module, Drupal 7 does not output any Microdata).

If you can’t decide between these two modules: Go with [schemaorg](https://drupal.org/project/schemaorg), because Drupal 7 already uses RDFa, [RDFa is more powerful than Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669), and parts of this module were ported into the Drupal 8 core.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've experienced Google picks up all of these formats. Sites I build use the default RDF module. I would not recommend running both modules as I could only it imagine adding a lot of bloat to your system.

I would visit Google's Structured Data Testing Tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Give all three modules a try, experiment with different pages and make a decision based off of those results. In the end there is no perfect SEO equation beyond what you think is proper.

Comment: Thanks, But currently I am on develop stage, on Aqcuia DEV desktop, so I can use this..
Is there any way to check this out?

Comment: I would try searching for an offline script then, I did find this: http://krofdrakula.github.io/microdata-tool/. It's a jQuery drop-in which calls out structured data. I'm guessing there has to be some better localized solution if you do some research.

**EDIT**: Here is a Gist that provides a bookmarklet for the above to do testing without adding the script. https://gist.github.com/peterhost/1397528